# Google Scripts - creating email sequences

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, gmail

Google Scripts question: I want to program a script that follows this pattern:

I  want to send from my email eg. abc@xyz.com to 123@@gmail.com (client's email)

There will be 6 type emails content which need to be sent over period of time like sequence, 1-2-3-4-5-6 every 5 days or 6 days as follow up

Essentially a sequence or follow up sequence.

Can someone point in the right direction?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `There will be 6 type emails content which need to be sent over period of time like sequence, 1-2-3-4-5-6 every 5 days or 6 days as follow up Essentially a sequence or follow up sequence.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script and more information of your goal?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask]  Can you edit your question and describe the issue with your current solution.   What have you done so far?  what are your issues?  please include [example]